# Attaching CRUD functions to drop down menu

Tags: html, angular, typescript, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I created the following tables below to represent the hierarchy of a specific job. Then I created some CRUD functions in java to "createJob", "getJob", "updateJob" and "deleteJob" in these tables.

Now I would like to implement the data I get back from these operations on a user interface. I'm looking for the simplest UI where I could probably have the job listed in a dropdown list and then based on my selection I can choose the job type then based on that selection choose the job specification.  These CRUD functions can be performed on each dropdown. To add a new Job, rename it, etc.

What's the simplest way to do this? I've been looking around for some APIs because I believe this would be something that's common. There is probably a more descriptive term for these types of drop downs which would help my search.

**EDIT** After further research, what I am looking for is an "Editable Cascading drop down list".

**EDIT 2** I was able to see some good examples using Angular to create the cascading drop down list.  I was able to create the app.component.ts and app.component.html below.  I can get the dropdowns to display but they are not cascading based on the Job selected.   What am I doing wrong in my code? Also, soon as this is working, how can I prepare the code to make use of the java functions I created earlier rather than the hard coded values I have?

```
+---------+---------+
| Id      |    Job  |                        
+---------+---------+
|     1  |Developer |                           
|
|     2  |QA Tester |  


+---------+---------+---------+-----+
| Id      |    Job_Type   | Job_Id                          
+---------+---------+---------+-----+
|     1 |Java Developer   |       1 |                           
|     2 |JS Developer     |       1 |
|     3 |FrontEnd Tester  |       2 |
|     4 |Backend Tester   |       2 |
|     5 |Php Developer    |       1 | 

+---------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
| Id      |    Job_Specification   | Job_Type_Id                          
+---------+---------+---------+----+-----------+
|     1 |Spring Developer          |       1 |                           
|     2 |Angular Developer         |       2 |
|     3 |UI Tester                 |       3 |
|     4 |Mobile Tester             |       3 |
|     5 |Hibernate Developer       |       1 |
```

**APP.COMPONENT.TS**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Roles!';
  selectedRole= 0;
  selectedProviderType = 0;

  providerType = [];
  classification = [];


  onSelectRole(role_id: number) {
    this.selectedRole = role_id;
    this.selectedProviderType = 0;
    this.classification = [];
    this.providerType = this.getProviderType().filter((item) => {
      return item.role_id === Number(role_id)
    });
  }
    onSelectProviderType(providerType_id: number) {
      this.selectedProviderType = providerType_id;
      this.classification = this.getClassification().filter((item) => {
        return item.providerType_id === Number(providerType_id)
      });
    }

getRoles() {
  return [
    { id: 1, name: 'Developer' },
    { id: 2, name: 'QA Tester' },
  ];
}

getProviderType() {
  return [
    { id: 1, role_id: 1, name: 'Java Developer' },
    { id: 2, role_id: 1, name: 'JS Developer' },
    { id: 3, role_id: 2, name: 'FrontEnd Tester' },
    { id: 4, role_id: 2, name: 'Backend Tester' },
    { id: 5, role_id: 3, name: 'Php Developer' },
  ]
}

getClassification() {
  return [
    { id: 1, providerType_id: 1, name: 'Spring Developer' },
    { id: 2, providerType_id: 1, name: 'Angular Developer ' },
    { id: 3, providerType_id: 1, name: 'UI Tester' },
    { id: 4, providerType_id: 1, name: 'Mobile Tester' },
    { id: 5, providerType_id: 2, name: 'Hibernate Developer' },
  ]
}
}
```

**APP.COMPONENT.HTML**

```
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Role">Role:</label>
  <select *ngIf="getRoles()" [(ngModel)]="selectedRole" (change)="onSelectRole($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="role">
     <option value="0">Select Role</option>
    <option *ngFor="let role of getRoles()" value= {{role.id}}>{{role.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="ProviderType">Provider Type:</label>
  <select *ngIf="getProviderType()" [(ngModel)]="selectedProviderType" (change)="onSelectProviderType($event.target.value)" class="form-control input-lg" id="providerType">
      <option value="0">Select Provider Type</option>
    <option *ngFor="let providerType of providerTypes" value= {{providerType.id}}>{{providerType.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Classification">Classification:</label>
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="classification">
      <option *ngIf="!selectedProviderType" value="0">Select Classification</option>
      <option *ngFor="let classification of classifications" value= {{classification.id}}>{{classification.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="Specification">Specification:</label>
  <select class="form-control input-lg" id="city">
      <option *ngIf="!selectedClassification" value="0">Select Specification</option>
      <option *ngFor="let specification of specifications" value= {{specification.id}}>{{specification.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: look into api php crude

Comment: do you have a relevant link to this? I'm not certain that what I have searched is exactly what I am looking for